# Set Border Thickness on JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border

I'm wondering if it is possible to adjust the thickness of a border around a JPanel in Java? I currently have a border defined and the JPanel adds the border around it but I would like it to be a little thicker:

```
Border border;
JPanel panel;

border = BorderFactory.creatLineBorder(Color.RED);
panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBorder(border);
```

Comment: How about reading the `LineBorder` API for the appropriate constructor or method? Read the API first before asking a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you could use `BorderFactory`

```
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(new BasicStroke(5.0f)));
```

See

- [BorderFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html)
- [BasicStroke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html)

Comment: You're missing an end bracket.

Answer (score 5):

BorderFactory has a method that accepts two parameters - the Color and thickness

```
border = BorderFactory.creatLineBorder(Color.RED, thickness);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [LineBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/LineBorder.html) class to generate a thicker line border

```
LineBorder border = new LineBorder(Color.RED, thickness)
panel.setBorder(border);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
 panel1.setBounds(0,0,201,201);
 panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE,3));
```

Note:Here border thickness is 3 and color is blue.